# How can I find the last insert ID with Node.js and Postgresql?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

When issuing an "insert" statement to postgres, how can I get the ID of the row last inserted in the DB?

I tried "pg", "pg-native", "pg-connection", and a bunch of other packages. For each package, I tried the `sync` and `async` method. I read the thing that pretends to be package documentation. I checked the source code for the packages. For the life of me I can't figure this out, and I can't believe that I'm the only person to face this issue.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

The key here is using `RETURNING id` in your INSERT query.

The pg wiki has [an example that shows how this is done](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/wiki/FAQ#7-i-just-have-a-question-and-maybe-a-feature-request-that-i-am-not-able-to-think-about-how-to-implement-or-do-it-i-need-to-retrieve-the-inserted-row-or-someway-to-reach-it-after-the-insert-is-done).

```
// Let's pretend we have a user table with the 'id' as the auto-incrementing primary key
var queryText = 'INSERT INTO users(password_hash, email) VALUES($1, $2) RETURNING id'
client.query(queryText, ['841l14yah', 'test@te.st'], function(err, result) {
  if (err) //handle error
  else {
    var newlyCreatedUserId = result.rows[0].id;
  }
});
```

or with `async/await`:

```
const result = await client.query(queryText, ['841l14yah', 'test@te.st']);
const newlyCreatedUserId = result.rows[0].id;
```

Comment: I tried your first technique during my initial investigation, but that didn't work. However, the "RETURNING id" part never occurred to me. Many thanks :)

Comment: I also missed the `RETURNING id` part, so I edited the answer to show this.

Comment: when I use CREATE result.rows appearing to be undefined, while post works. How to find out ID of NW entry in this case?

Comment: Guys, don't forget about the last "RETURNING id" part